# How do I add URL parameters to default.xml when creating menu items?

Tags: menu-item, menu-parameters

For my component I added a default.xml file to create the menu item. This all works good but the URL generated for this menu item needs a few extra parameters. In my case format=raw and task=start.

I am at a loss how to get the menu URL to add these parameters. I tried to add them as hidden form items in the default.xml but then the parameters are added to the URL but with no value.

Is it possible to have Joomla append these 2 parameters?

Thanks.

Edit: I found the mistake I made why it didn't work.

You can add these paramters like this:
< field name="task" type="hidden" default="start"/ >

That is all that is needed :)

Answer (score 3):

you need add a "request" fields group, something like:

```
<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request">
       <field name="format" type="hidden" default="raw"/>
       <field name="task" type="hidden" default="start"/>
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, I had the code in my comment but can't make it show. I have now added spaces so it actually shows up.

Comment: I found here detailed example - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/how-do-i-get-a-menu-item-to-send-a-parameter-to-a-component/10548#10548